# Show JSON data objects in React Native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, react-native, picker

I'm working on a little project which related to connecting API's on React Native. In that, I got a JSON data object like this.

```
{
  success: 1,
  data: {
    monthly_income: {
      0: {
        en: 'Below Ten Thousand',
        expect_en: 'Neglected',
      },
      10000: {
        en: 'Above Ten Thousand',
      },
      25000: {
        en: 'Above Twenty Thousand',
      },
      50000: {
        en: 'Above Fifty Thousand',
      },
      75000: {
        en: 'Above Seventy Five Thousand',
      },
      100000: {
        en: 'Above Hundred Thousand',
      },
    },
    height: {
      5: {
        en: '5 Feet',
      },
      5.1: {
        en: '5 Feet and 1 Inches',
      },
      5.2: {
        en: '5 Feet and 2 Inches',
      },
      5.3: {
        en: '5 Feet and 3 Inches',
      },
      5.4: {
        en: '5 Feet and 4 Inches',
      },
      5.5: {
        en: '5 Feet and 5 Inches',
      },
      5.6: {
        en: '5 Feet and 6 Inches',
      },
      5.7: {
        en: '5 Feet and 7 Inches',
      },
      5.8: {
        en: '5 Feet and 8 Inches',
      },
      5.9: {
        en: '5 Feet and 9 Inches',
      },
      '5.10': {
        en: '5 Feet and 10 Inches',
      },
      5.11: {
        en: '5 Feet and 11 Inches',
      },
      6: {
        en: '6 Feet',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I wanted to display above data in a React Native picker in separately, like a Monthly Income in one picker & Height in another picker. I tried using map method to do that, but I couldn't  access to the data inside this. My questions are,

- Can we use map method to access these kinds of JSON objects?
- If we can, what is the best way to do that?
- If can't, please suggest the way to do that work

Comment: Assume your object is `someObj`, then the monthly-incomes can be shown using `<p>`   tags (or, use `<Text>` instead of `<p>`) like so: `<div>{Object.entries(someObj.monthly_income).map(([k, v]) => (<p>Amount: {k}</p><br/><p>Description: {v}</p><br/>))}</div>`. Please try to see if it shows-up within `<p>` or `<Text>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fernando suggests, transform object to array.

I build full working example for further details.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Picker } from "@react-native-picker/picker";

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from "./components/AssetExample";

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from "react-native-paper";
import response from "./response";

const getMonthlyIncomes = (response) => {
  let monthlyIncomes = response.data.monthly_income;

  const keys = Object.keys(monthlyIncomes);

  return keys.map((key) => {
    let incomeData = monthlyIncomes[key];

    return { value: key, ...incomeData };
  });
};

const getHeights = (response) => {
  let heights = response.data.height;

  const keys = Object.keys(heights);

  return keys.map((key) => {
    let heightData = heights[key];

    return { value: key, ...heightData };
  });
};

const monthlyIncomes = getMonthlyIncomes(response);
const heights = getHeights(response);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Monthly Income</Text>
          <Picker>
            {monthlyIncomes.map((income) => {
              return (
                <Picker.Item
                  key={income.value}
                  label={income.en}
                  value={income.value}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </Card>

      {/** Heights */}

      <Card style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
          <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Heights</Text>
          <Picker>
            {heights.map((height) => {
              return (
                <Picker.Item
                  key={height.value}
                  label={height.en}
                  value={height.value}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Picker>
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Expo Snack - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/9b1520

Comment: That make me more clear. Convert objects in to an array and use with map.  Also, we can use that key as its Value, of course.  Thanks for the example, sir.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn this into an array to be able to map it.

Try something like:

```
{Object.keys(JSON_NAME.data.monthly_income).map((key) => {
  return <Text>JSON_NAME.data.monthly_Income[key] </Text>
})}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot   

 Object.keys(response.data.data).map(key => {
          console.log(key);
          console.log(response.data.data[key]);
        });
      })